# Error al pasar datos de un DataTable a página PrimeFaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tengo un error al pasar los datos seleccionados de mi `dataTable` a otra página. Cuando me abre la otra pagina, no me muestra nada, me sale en blanco. 
Este es mi código de la página:

```
<p:dataTable id="pa" value="#{cargarArchivo.listdatos}" var="p" rows="10"
             paginator="true" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
             currentPageReportTemplate="Registros Totales: {totalRecords}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Página: {currentPage} de {totalPages}"
             draggableColumns="true" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,50,100,150"
             selection="#{cargarArchivo.datosSeleccionado}" selectionMode="single"
             rowKey="#{p}"
             emptyMessage="No tiene ningun registro">
    <p:column headerText="Fecha">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{p.fecha}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
        </p:outputLabel>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Mezcla">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{p.mezcla}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Hora Llegada">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{p.horaI}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="hh:mm:ss" />
        </p:outputLabel>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Hora Salida">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{p.horaF}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="hh:mm:ss" />
        </p:outputLabel>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Toneladas">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{p.peso}">
            <f:convertNumber pattern="#0.00" />
        </p:outputLabel>    
    </p:column>

    <p:column width="80">
        <f:facet name="header"><p:outputLabel value="Opciones"/></f:facet>
        <p:commandLink value="abrir" actionListener="#{verTicket.abrirTicket(p)}">

        </p:commandLink>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Y en verTicket tengo lo siguiente:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class verTicket {

private datos datos;

public void init() {
    System.out.println(datos.getFecha());
}

public void abrirTicket(datos dato) {
    try {
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        externalContext.redirect(externalContext.getApplicationContextPath() + "/paginas/crearTicket.xhtml");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

}

public datos getDatos() {
    return datos;
}

public void setDatos(datos datos) {
    this.datos = datos;
}

}
```

Esta es la página donde se van a mostrar los datos seleccionados:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
 <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="estilo2.css"/>
  <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="estilo.css"/>
    <h:head>
      <title>Crear Ticket</title>
    </h:head>
      <h:body>
           Hello Mundo!!
           <p:outputLabel value="#{verTicket.datos.fecha}"/>
           </h:body>
          </html>
```

Comment: Será por el valor del ´rowKey´, este debería ser el **ID** que representa cada fila

Answer (score 1):

Los Managed Beans marcados con la anotación `@ViewScoped`no guardan la información al navegar a otras páginas. Para ello tienes que declararlos como `@SessionScoped` o `@ApplicationScoped`, dependiendo de cuánto tiempo deben mantenerse en memoria.

Answer (score 0):

Como @RobertoLinares dice, los `beans` que tienen como `scope` `ViewScoped` no conservan los datos al navegar entre vistas.
Si lo deseas, deberías de cambiar el scope a `SessionScoped` o si lo dejas en `ViewScoped` deberás implementar algo con parámetros de esta manera.

Este es solo código de ejemplo:

```
<p:commandLink action="FrmAfiliados.xhtml" value=" Modificar " styleClass="botonBoot">
    <f:param name="accion" value="Modificar"/> 
    <f:param name="idAfiliado" value="#{dato.idAfiliado}"/>   
    <f:param name="deptoVive" value="#{dato.idMunicipio.idDepto.idDepto}"/>
    <f:param name="deptoNacimiento" value="#{dato.idMunicipioNacimiento.idDepto.idDepto}"/>                            
</p:commandLink>
```

Y en el `bean`:

```
Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
accion = params.get("accion") != null ? params.get("accion") : "";
```

Un `param.get("")` por cada parámetro que has pasado.

Comment: intente probar tu codigo pero no funciona

Comment: @darksihart con tu código ¿cómo te quedó?

Comment: hay un detalle los datos no son solos string  puede ser por el map que me genere el error pero mi codigo quedo asi  {   <p:commandLink value="abrir" action="crearTicket.xhtml">
                        <f:param name="fecha" value="#{verTicket.datos.fecha}"/> 

                    </p:commandLink>}

Comment: ¿Te ha funcionado lo de pasar los parámetros, entonces?

Comment: no sigo sin poder mostrar los datos en la otra pagina

Comment: La cosa de usar los parámetros es que luego, para pasar a la otra página y obtener el dato, en el método `@PostContruct` debes buscar el dato... Podrías pasar por parámetro solo el ID de la entidad en el método del `@PostContruct` obtener el valor y realizar la búsqueda del ID que has pasado por parámetro... esa es la idea, porque a través de parámetros no puedes pasar objetos.

Comment: si amigo pero no uso base de datos yo lleno mi datatable con un archivo txt quiero seleccionar esos datos y pasarlos a la otra pagina

Comment: Ah ya entendí. Es solo texto, debería poder pasarse por parámetros.

Comment: amigo eh tratado varias formas y no logro obtener esos valores

Answer (score 0):

En el método `abrirTicket` te falta especificar que la variable que declaraste `private datos datos;` es igual al parámetro que le estas pasando al método.

Agregándolo así debería solucionarse:

```
public void abrirTicket(datos dato) {
    try {
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        datos=dato;
        externalContext.redirect(externalContext.getApplicationContextPath() + "/paginas/crearTicket.xhtml");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```